# Can't find IOR and Density value nodes

Tags: node-editor

I can't find these two nodes (**IOR** and **Density**):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are default **Value** nodes (*Add> Input> Value*), just renamed by user to make node-tree more "understandable".

*Original node:*

[image]

To rename any node open *N-Panel* in *Node Editor* window (press <kbd>N</kbd>) and type anything in *Label* field.

*Renamed:*

[image]

Comment: maybe you should explain how to rename (N panel > Node > Label)